# How reset or change admin passwd in EduBuntu 14.04?

Tags: permissions, password, root, password-recovery, edubuntu

My fault... I created a new PC for my family some time ago and I lost the passwd for my (unique) admin user.
I can access with other users, but none of them has admin priviledges.

I tried the solution found on web to enter the system in recovery mode (left shift), do a "mount -rw -o remount /" and then try (as root) to "passwd ", but i always get "Permission denied / password unchanged".

Why - as a root user - cannot I change an admin password?

Probably I did one year ago some system changes/updates to try running Scracth for my kids (running Adobe Air) and modified some passwd settings that I cannot remember :(

Might you please help me?

Comment: Can you create a new admin user from the recovery shell?

Comment: Thanks for the help: I'll give asap a check and let you know.  Will I have to use the "useradd" command with specific parameters, correct?